# BrowserSync Not Reloading Changes

Tags: browser-sync

I started BrowserSync with this command:

```
browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8001 --files "app/css/*.css"
```

I have the code snippet in index.html and when I open the page in my browser, I see the message:

```
Connected to BrowserSync
```

But when I make changes to the CSS, the BrowserSync does not reload the page with the changes.  I have to manually reload to see the change.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is `--files="app/css/*.css"` and not `--files "app/css/*.css"`
2. Browsersync reads `index.html` by default, hence you get the message `'Connected to browsersync'`

And here's the solution to your answer..

In every forum I have checked, everyone is following the same nomenclature of `"css/*.css"`. Without realizing what the initial `css` stands for. Its the name of the folder or directory not something for vague..

Hence, make sure that inside those quotes you have pointed to the right directory. For example, if the `styles.css` file is just outside (i.e. in the root directory) alongside `index.html`, then just write `--files="styles.css"`. It shall work like charm.

And if you want `Browsersync` to watch multiple css files then put `--files="*.css"`. If you want to sync different types of files, then use `--files="*.html,*.js"`.

If these css files are in some directory say `'xfolder'` then `--files="xfolder/*.css"`